# How to properly fire the click event in a contextmenu in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, gridview

So I am trying to create a click event for one of my contextmenu items but it's throwing me an error I have never seen before.
There wasnt too much information on Google and the information I saw didnt help me because I didnt understand it.

The line throwing the error is this one

> GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1}"

saying

> 'cmndOP_Click' is not valid. 'Click' is not an event on
>   'System.Windows.Controls.GridView'.

Reading the error message tells me that 'Click' is not a valid event in the gridview, but its not in the gridview its in the listviewitem.

Whats causing this error and what should I do in the future to prevent this?

```
<ListView Margin="10,36,520,10" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="-1, -1, 1, 0" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1.000001" Name="lvUsers"  Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle1}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Name="cmndOP" Header="OP User" Click="cmndOP_Click"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Kick User"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Ban User"/>
                                <MenuItem Header="Send Command"/>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                <Border
                         BorderBrush="Transparent"
                         BorderThickness="0"
                         Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                                    <GridViewRowPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Width="Auto" Margin="0" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>

                    </Setter>

                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#696969" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#696969" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#696969" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#696969" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1}">
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="GridViewColumnName" Header="Name" Width="165">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image x:Name="Image_GridViewColumnName" Width="16" Height="16" Source="Images\minecraft.png" />
                                    <Label Content="{Binding Username}" Visibility="Visible" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>

            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

And this behind it

```
private void cmndOP_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Commands cmd = new Commands();
            cmd.OpUser(lvUsers.SelectedItem.ToString());
        }
```

EDIT

This is where the error happands.
This is also in the App.xaml because otherwise I would get another error

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Transparent">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ContentHeader" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="5,5,5,5" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" TextAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
        </Style>
```

Comment: How about you show us `GridViewColumnHeaderStyle1` where it appears that the problem is actually happening? Did you paste the error text into your question without reading it?

Comment: Why do you want to fire the event?  Why not put the code that is in the event handler into a separate method and just call that method?

Comment: Ahh gotcha! Updating it right away!

Comment: The string `cmndOP_Click` appears nowhere in any of the above XAML. I think you should try to find it in your XAML files. It appears that somewhere, you are trying to use `cmndOP_Click` as a Click event on a GridView, but `GridView` has no Click event. You need to find where you are doing that. If you are not actually doing that anywhere, a clean build and a VS restart may be in order.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry just saw that I had some old code there, updated it, it now has the event in the <MenuItem Name="cmndOP". Sorry about that

Comment: That's a MenuItem, not a GridView. The error message is talking about a GridView.

Comment: Yeah and the error appears when I add the click event handler in the menu item, because I want something to happen when I click the menuitem

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Because I want something to happen when I clickt hat specific menuitem

Comment: But it sounds like you are trying to click the button _programatically_!  If that is the case, just use a method and call it directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was surprised to find that your error was reproducible from the XAML you provided. When I define the context menu as a resource and update the setter accordingly, I no longer get the error.

```
<ListView Margin="10,36,520,10" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" BorderBrush="Black" Padding="-1, -1, 1, 0" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1.000001" Name="lvUsers"  >
    <ListView.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="ListViewItemContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Name="cmndOP" Header="OP User" Click="cmndOP_Click" />
            <MenuItem Header="Kick User"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Ban User"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Send Command"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ListViewItemContextMenu}" />
```